# Calculate Time difference between two operation using kusto query

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

I would like to Calculate Time difference between two operation where operation name contains ID using kusto query. please find attached snapshot that contains table and required output. It would be helpful if anyone can share Kusto query to achieve the same.

```
timestamp [IST]                 name
2022/30/6, 4:10:00.460 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached Three
2022/30/6, 4:12:00.091 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached Two
2022/30/6, 4:10:00.460 AM   ewerewtetete-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667 Retry message
2022/30/6, 4:14:10.791 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached One
2022/30/6, 4:15:10.460 AM   ewerewtetete-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached Three
2022/30/6, 4:20:04.343 AM   fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667 Retry message
```

Output

```
Time Difference by operationID(which is part of name) in seconds
fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667    604
ewerewtetete-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667 310
```

Comment: Hi David, I have updated data in text format. thanks for your help. difference can be in an format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
datatable(['timestamp [IST]']:datetime, name:string)
[
    "2022-06-30 04:10:00.460" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached Three"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:12:00.091" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached Two"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:10:00.460" ,"ewerewtetete-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667 Retry message"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:14:10.791" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached One"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:15:10.460" ,"ewerewtetete-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667  Success: Reached Three"
   ,"2022-06-30 04:20:04.343" ,"fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667 Retry message"
]  
|   project-rename ts = ['timestamp [IST]']
|   parse name with OperationID " " *
|   summarize TimeDiffSec = round((max(ts) - min(ts)) / 1s) by OperationID
```

| OperationID | TimeDiffSec |
| --- | --- |
| fbf759a0-d4be-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667 | 604 |
| ewerewtetete-4d07-adfb-7090a207e667 | 310 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA6XSsW7CMBAG4Jk8xSkLocL0CCERkbqxMCERNsTgxBdwVSeRbZRS8fC1OyEEUhG%20xfLw6fevE9y6Kb8o2g2tVGQsVx3sVsV2P9znglvyr2NouKLcWC2bwyjYBeBOGGMcM0zZDAGTfIo54iRJMYRxWJd1Nl9wZCIpiSUCM8ZFXbIMF8hjzChNM4DiVFVkTA4b4tWRBGyPmij0%20vhWj72Oi%20kret/et6%20TU0%20aevdtN4/oDVl9BleW4YcHcb06yV6Ku24e2HNvPxH3mZ5j10UymSWzfwe/KWMPEFwGnW4/qbJMk18csAY%204M6CBRcYdFwb%20tsv6KU9wrojza1sm9USQjdvjjMnpbiWPwRbRyxlXRdUOVK3p0ZEkeLfkTUjYKBk428jeIepeyjP19wv0tr1xOwCAAA=)